# need finite 'xlim' values on Zoo object plotting

Tags: python, r, plot, zoo

I have the following zoo object :

`x<-read.zoo("values.txt",format="%H:%M:%OS",sep=",",header=F,FUN=as.POSIXct)`

x is like the below:

> 2015-01-20 17:39:56  367   0
>       2015-01-20 17:39:56  236   0
>       2015-01-20 17:39:58  542   0
>       2015-01-20 17:39:58  260   0

Now I aggregate over the second time interval to get values per second instead of the millisecond level: 
`> x_uniq<-aggregate(x,format(time(x),"%H:%M:%S"),mean)`

x_uniq is like the below :

> 17:39:55  403.0000   0.0
>   17:39:56  301.5000   0.0
>   17:39:58  401.0000   0.0
>   17:40:00  607.0000   0.0

Whe I try to plot it however I get the below error:

`plot(x_uniq,plot.type = "single", col = c("red", "blue"),lwd = 2)`
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Now it is, the way I understand it, because the times have now been converted to characters. But I am not sure how to convert this back. Could anyone please help? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question omitted the input and only showed the output of the `read.zoo` statement so we don't really know what you have but assuming it looks like the following try this:

```
Lines <- 
"2015-01-20 17:39:56,367,0
2015-01-20 17:39:56,236,0
2015-01-20 17:39:58,542,0
2015-01-20 17:39:58,260,0"

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, sep = ",", tz = "", aggregate = mean)
plot(z)
```